# Style Rails collection_check_boxes

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I been trying to apply some CSS classes to collection_check_boxes but I can't get it to work. Right now I doing this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:brand_ids, Brand.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
        <%= b.label { b.check_box + b.text } %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

which outputs this HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="user_brand_ids_1">
        <input id="user_brand_ids_1" name="user[brand_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1">Brand 1
    </label>
    <input name="user[brand_ids][]" type="hidden" value=""> 
</div>
```

Instead I would like to output this HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="label-checkbox" for="user_brand_ids_1">
        <input id="user_brand_ids_1" name="user[brand_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1">
        <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>Brand 1
    </label>
    <input name="user[brand_ids][]" type="hidden" value=""> 
</div>
```

I've tried the following, which doesn't work...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:brand_ids, Brand.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: 'label-checkbox'}) do |b| %>
        <%= b.label { b.check_box + b.text }, class: 'label-checkbox' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how could I do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:brand_ids, Brand.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
        <%= b.label class:"label-checkbox" do%>
         <%=b.check_box + b.text%>
        <%end%>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I splitted the <%=b.check_box + b.text%>, so I could add the span label <%= b.check_box %><span class="custom-checkbox"></span><%= b.text %>. But passing that second block was the key.

Answer (score 5):

A little shorter to use an inline block

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:brand_ids, Brand.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
  <%= b.label(class:"label-checkbox") { b.check_box + b.text } %>
<% end %>
```