# Rails - bootstrap_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I use bootstrap_form_for but I encounterded an issue. I use "collection_check_boxes" helper and I can't set custom class for checkbox label or checkbox input. I read the documentation and I couldn't find how to do it.

```
= bootstrap_form_for :xxx do |f|

  ...

  .form-group
    = f.fields_for :books do |bf|
      = bf.collection_check_boxes(:id, Book.all, :id, :name, label: 'Books')
```

Comment: try this and tell me whether it works for you or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770491/style-rails-collection-check-boxes

Comment: I've tried it and it does not work. It works only for nornal form_for but not for bootstrap_form_for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer:
https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms/issues/256

Summing up: It's not possible so far